# `define in generate if statement

Tags: verilog, generate

This generates single bit out, for all values of parameter `syn`. Why for `syn>0` its not generating 2 bit out

```
module test
        (clk,
         rst_n,
         en,
         rst_n2,
         in,
         out
         );

parameter syn=0;

generate if(syn>0)begin 
    `define ROMS
end endgenerate

input clk;
input rst_n;
input en;
input rst_n2;



`ifdef ROMS
    input  in;
    output reg  out;
`endif



`ifndef ROMS
    input [1:0] in;
    output reg [1:0] out;
`endif



always_ff@(posedge clk or negedge rst_n or negedge en) begin 
    if(~rst_n) begin 
         out <= 0;
     end else if(clk) begin 
         out <= 0;
     end else if(rst_n2 == 1'b0)begin 
         out <= 0;
     end else begin     
         out <= in;
     end 
end

endmodule
```

Comment: Welcome to Stackoverflow. Please provide more explanation to your code, so other can understand.

Comment: Yes, why was this closed? I have no problems at all understanding the question (although it *was* badly formatted before @octobus edited it)

Comment: @Oldfart How about voting to reopen it?

Comment: @octobus thanks for formatting my code. My question was irrespective of parameter syn value , `ifdef ROMS was getting compiled, But as Matthew answered , compiler directive gets evaluated before code is compiled so ROMS is always defined.

Comment: In this particular case you are only determining with bit widths of `in` and `out`, so you could use `module test #(parameter WIDTH=1) (input clk, rst_in, en, rst_n2, input [WIDTH-1:0] in, output reg [WIDTH-1:0] out);` (ANSI style header). Also note your `clk` is not being used as a clock, but as an async reset. And `negedge en` is begin treated as a synchronous clock.

Answer (score 2):

Because `define is a *compile directive*. It is evaluated before your code is compiled.  `ROMS is always defined, whatever the value of `syn`.

Comment: Yes this makes sense. Thanks

Comment: is there a way to remove input/output ports during compile time depending on parameter value? ex. if parameter NUM_ROMS is >0 than i want to add rom related ports otherwise I don't want to add those ports.

Comment: @KEVINGAJERA Not using a parameter value, no. You can give default values to ports and then leave them unconnected, however.